# Unit Testing, using properties to pass in an interface

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0

Im reading "The art of unit testing" atm and im having some issues with using properties to pass in an interface. The book states the following: "If you want parameters to be optional, use property getters/setters, which is a better way of defining optional parameters than adding different constructors to the class for each dependency."

The code for the property example is as follows:

```
public class LogAnalyzer
{
    private IExtensionManager manager;
    public LogAnalyzer ()
    {
        manager = new FileExtensionManager();
    }

    public IExtensionManager ExtensionManager
    {
        get { return manager; }
        set { manager = value; }
    }

    public bool IsValidLogFileName(string fileName)
    {
        return manager.IsValid(fileName);
    }
}

[Test]
Public void
IsValidFileName_NameShorterThan6CharsButSupportedExtension_ReturnsFalse()
{
    //set up the stub to use, make sure it returns true
    ...
    //create analyzer and inject stub
    LogAnalyzer log = new LogAnalyzer ();
    log.ExtensionManager=someFakeManagerCreatedEarlier;

    //Assert logic assuming extension is supported
    ...
}
```

When/how would i use this feature?? The only scenario i can think of (This is probably wrong!) is if i had two methods in one class,

Method1() retrieves the database connection string from the config file and contains some form of check on the retrieved string.

Method2() then connect to the database and returns some data. The check here could be that that returned data is not null?

In this case, to test Method1() i could declare a stub that implements the IExtensionManager Interface, where the stub has a string which should pass any error checks i have in method1().

For Method2(), i declare a stub which implements the interface, and declare a datatable which contains some data, in the stub class. id then use the properties to assign this to the private manager variable and then call Method2?

**The above may be complete BS**, so if it is, id appreciate it if someone would let me know and ill remove it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Property injection used to change object's behavior after it was created.

BTW your code is tight coupled to `FileExtensionManager`, which is concrete implementation of `IExtensionManager`. How you are going to test `LogAnalyzer` with default manager? Use constructor injection to provide dependencies to your objects - this will make them testable:

```
public LogAnalyzer (IExtensionManager manager)
{
    this.manager = manager();
}
```

Comment: hi, the code is from the book. regarding your comment "How are you going to test LogAnalyzer with default manager?" i thought whenever an instance of LogAnalyzer was created, manager was initially set to default. It was only when performing tests that i change it via the properties, or am i missing something?

Comment: @HansRudel yes, manager is set to default (this is called poor man's dependency injection). But you will need to replace it with mocked manager for tests. And this kind of dependency is not desired if default is declared in other assembly - you will be coupled to that assembly. Also injecting manager instance with DI frameworks is easier when you use constructor injection. Using poor man's injection is not `wrong`, but I prefer to depend on abstractions only.

Comment: is it possible to have 5mins of your time in a chat room? (i dont have sufficient rep to open one)

Comment: Thanks. Just give me a shout when your ready or come into the c# chat room. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c